# Is there a Python structure that combines `while` and `with`?

Tags: python

I have some code that looks like this.

```
condition = <expression>
while condition:
    <some code>
```

I would like to be able to write that without having to write a separate statement to create the condition. E.g.,

```
while <create_condition(<expression>)>:
    <some code>
```

Here are two possibilities that don't work, but that would scratch my itch.

```
with <expression> as condition:
    <some code>
```

The problem with that is that it doesn't loop. If I embed a **`while`** inside the **`with`** I'm back where I started.

Define my own function to do this.

```
def looping_with(<expression>, <some code>):
   <define looping_with>
```

The problem with this is that if `<some code>` is passed as a **`lambda`** expression it is limited to a single expression. None of the workarounds I've seen are attractive.

If `<some code>` is passed as an actual **`def`** one gets a syntax error. You can't pass a function definition as an argument to another function.

One could define the function elsewhere and then pass the function. But the point of **`with`**, **`while`**, and **`lambda`** is that the code itself, not a reference to the code, is embedded in context. (The original version of my code, which is not terrible, is better than that.)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: (As Dave Beazley likes to say: You're going to hate this.)
I hesitate to offer this example, but this is something like what I'm trying to do.

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

class Get_Next:

    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen

    def __call__(self, limit, container):
        self.runnable_gen = self.gen(limit, container)
        return self

    def get_next(self):
        try:
            next(self.runnable_gen)
            return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False


@Get_Next
def a_generator(limit, container):
    i = 0
    while i < limit:
        container.value = i
        yield
        i += 1


container = Container()

gen = a_generator(5, container)
while gen.get_next():
    print(container.value)
print('Done')
```

When run, the output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Done
```

**P.S.** Lest you think this is too far out, there is a very easy way to produce the same result. Remove the decorator from `a_generator` and then run:

```
for _ in a_generator(5, container):
    print(container.value)
print('Done')
```

The result is the same.

The problem is that `for _ in <something>` is too ugly for me.

So, what I'm really looking for is a way to get the functionality of `for _ in <something>` with nicer syntax. The syntax should (a) indicate that we are establishing a context and (b) looping within that context. Hence the request for a combination of `with` and `while`.

Comment: try a do-while loop https://coderwall.com/p/q_rd1q/emulate-do-while-loop-in-python

Comment: This seems like far too rare a thing to warrant a dedicated syntax construct.

Comment: "The idea is that the second argument would be an actual def. But you can't pass a function definition as an argument to another function." You can pass *any* function. Why does it have to be in-line? In any case, when Python 3.8 comes out wiht the assignment expression, you'll be able to do what you want. Personally, I think it makes the code less readable. But to each their own.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Assignment expressions don't quite handle this, because `while (condition := expression)` would reevaluate the expression every time. The posted code only evaluates it once and then only changes the `condition` value if some code in the loop body changes it, and there's no indication it gets changed in the loop body. I don't get what this code is going for.

Comment: @user2357112 ah yes, good point. So then I will double down on just keeping the code how it is :)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking for. What do you want that `while <expression>:` doesn't do?

Comment: Can you provide a *concrete* example of some code that you would like to rewrite in a way that you currently cannot?

Comment: Why not just have the generator yield `container.value`?

Comment: The problem isn't with getting `container.value` out. The problem is with how the source code looks.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Container`? You don't use it for anything except holding the value generated by `a_generator`? Your example just seems too contrived to convey what you are really after. What's ugly about `for _ in ...`?

Comment: You're right about the purpose of the container. Values are returned through it rather than through a `yield` or `return` statement. It would take too long to explain why I want to do that, but that's exactly what I want to do. I find the `for` statement ugly because it so explicitly implies that values are returned from the iterator in the normal way. But since the receiving variable is an underscore, those values are then ignored. I don't want to impose the burden of that implicit semantics. The real semantics is that values are returned through arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) `class` that would help in doing something like that:

```
class Condition:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cond(*args, **kwargs)


with Condition(lambda x: x != 3) as condition:
    a = 0
    while condition(a):
        print('a:', a)
        a += 1
```

Output:

```
a: 0
a: 1
a: 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's one of the options I mentioned, i.e., a `with` with an embedded `while`. It does the job, but I'd like a single construct.